# CIFAR-10 test set classification accuracy different on PyTorch and Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I’ve made a custom CNN in PyTorch for classifying 10 classes in the CIFAR-10 dataset. My classification accuracy on the test dataset is 45.739%, this is very low and I thought it’s because my model is not very deep but I implemented the same model in Keras and the classification accuracy come outs to be 78.92% on test dataset. No problem in Keras however I think there's something I'm missing in my PyTorch program.

I have used the same model architecture, strides, padding, dropout rate, optimizer, loss function, learning rate, batch size, number of epochs on both PyTorch and Keras and despite that, the difference in the classification accuracy is still huge thus I’m not able to decide how I should debug my PyTorch program further.

For now I suspect 3 things: in Keras, I use the categorical cross entropy loss function (one hot vector labels) and in PyTorch I use the standard cross entropy loss function (scalar indices labels), can this be a problem?, if not then I suspect either my training loop or the code for calculating classification accuracy in PyTorch. I have attached both my programs below, will be grateful to any suggestions.

My program in Keras:

```
#================Function that defines the CNN model===========
def CNN_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same', input_shape=(size,size,channels))) #SAME PADDING
    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu')) #VALID PADDING
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) #VALID PADDING
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')) #SAME PADDING
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu')) #VALID PADDING
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))) #VALID PADDING
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))


    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')) #SAME PADDING
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu')) #VALID PADDING
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),name='feature_extractor_layer')) #VALID PADDING
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))


    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', name='second_last_layer'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='softmax_layer')) #10 nodes in the softmax layer
    model.summary()

    return model



#=====Main program starts here========
#get_train_data() and get_test_data() are my own custom functions to get CIFAR-10 dataset
images_train, labels_train, class_train = get_train_data(0,10)
images_test, labels_test, class_test = get_test_data(0,10)

model = CNN_model()


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', #loss function of the CNN
             optimizer=Adam(lr=1.0e-4), #Optimizer
              metrics=['accuracy'])#'accuracy' metric is to be evaluated

#images_train and images_test contain images and 
#class_train and class_test contains one hot vectors labels 
model.fit(images_train,class_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=50,
          validation_data=(images_test,class_test),
          verbose=1)

scores=model.evaluate(images_test,class_test,verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: "+str(scores[1]*100)+"% \n")
```

My program in PyTorch:

```
#========DEFINE THE CNN MODEL=====
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3,1,1)#SAME PADDING
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32,32,3,1,0)#VALID PADDING
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2) #VALID PADDING
        self.drop1 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25) #DROPOUT OF 0.25

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32,64,3,1,1)#SAME PADDING
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(64,64,3,1,0)#VALID PADDING
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)#VALID PADDING
        self.drop2 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25) #DROPOUT OF 0.25

        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(64,128,3,1,1)#SAME PADDING
        self.conv6 = nn.Conv2d(128,128,3,1,0)#VALID PADDING
        self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)#VALID PADDING
        self.drop3 = nn.Dropout2d(0.25) #DROPOUT OF 0.25

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128*2*2, 512)#128*2*2 IS OUTPUT DIMENSION AFTER THE PREVIOUS LAYER 
        self.drop4 = nn.Dropout(0.25) #DROPOUT OF 0.25
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512,10) #10 output nodes


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)


        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.drop2(x)

        x = F.relu(self.conv5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv6(x))
        x = self.pool3(x)
        x = self.drop3(x)


        x = x.view(-1,2*2*128) #FLATTENING OPERATION 2*2*128 IS OUTPUT AFTER THE PREVIOUS LAYER
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.drop4(x)
        x = self.fc2(x) #LAST LAYER DOES NOT NEED SOFTMAX BECAUSE THE LOSS FUNCTION WILL TAKE CARE OF IT
        return x



#=======FUNCTION TO CONVERT INPUT AND TARGET TO TORCH TENSORS AND LOADING INTO GPU======
def PrepareInputDataAndTargetData(device,images,labels,batch_size):

    #GET MINI BATCH OF TRAINING IMAGES AND RESHAPE THE TORCH TENSOR FOR CNN PROCESSING
    mini_batch_images = torch.tensor(images)
    mini_batch_images = mini_batch_images.view(batch_size,3,32,32)

    #GET MINI BATCH OF TRAINING LABELS, TARGET SHOULD BE IN LONG FORMAT SO CONVERT THAT TOO
    mini_batch_labels = torch.tensor(labels)
    mini_batch_labels = mini_batch_labels.long()

    #FEED THE INPUT DATA AND TARGET LABELS TO GPU
    mini_batch_images = mini_batch_images.to(device)
    mini_batch_labels = mini_batch_labels.to(device)

    return mini_batch_images,mini_batch_labels

#==========MAIN PROGRAM==========
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
#get_train_data() and get_test_data() are my own custom functions to get CIFAR-10 dataset 
Images_train, Labels_train, Class_train = get_train_data(0,10)
Images_test, Labels_test, Class_test = get_test_data(0,10)

net = Net()
net = net.double() #https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-expected-object-of-scalar-type-double-but-got-scalar-type-float-for-argument-2-weight/38961
print(net)

#MAP THE MODEL ONTO THE GPU
net = net.to(device)

#CROSS ENTROPY LOSS FUNCTION AND ADAM OPTIMIZER
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

#PREPARE THE DATALOADER
#Images_train contains images and Labels_trains contains indices i.e. 0,1,...,9 
dataset = TensorDataset( Tensor(Images_train), Tensor(Labels_train) )
trainloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size= 128, shuffle=True)

#START TRAINING THE CNN MODEL FOR 50 EPOCHS
for epoch in range(0,50):
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        inputs, labels = data
        inputs = torch.tensor(inputs).double()
        inputs = inputs.view(len(inputs),3,32,32) #RESHAPE THE IMAGES
        labels = labels.long() #MUST CONVERT LABEL TO LONG FORMAT

        #MAP THE INPUT AND LABELS TO THE GPU
        inputs=inputs.to(device)
        labels=labels.to(device)

        #FORWARD PROP, BACKWARD PROP, PARAMETER UPDATE
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net.forward(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


#CALCULATE CLASSIFICATION ACCURACY ON ALL 10 CLASSES
with torch.no_grad():
    Images_class,Labels_class = PrepareInputDataAndTargetData(device,Images_test,Labels_test,len(Images_test))
    network_outputs = net.forward(Images_class)
    correct = (torch.argmax(network_outputs.data,1) == Labels_class.data).float().sum()
    acc = float(100.0*(correct/len(Images_class)))
    print("Accuracy is: "+str(acc)+"\n")

    del Images_class
    del Labels_class
    del network_outputs
    del correct
    del acc
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()


print("Done\n")
```

I am not fully aware of how the actual core backend works in both libraries however I suppose that the classification accuracy of any model should be almost the same regardless of the library.

Comment: Most probable guess is you are doing model.eval() before testing/computing acc with torch. Hence, module like dropout which behave different on train/test won't work properly

Comment: @UmangGupta , thank you for your suggestion. Yes what you say makes sense. I added net.eval() before my accuracy computation but still the overall accuracy is still the same compared to if I don't add net.eval() before accuracy computation. Any suggestions you have?